# Epsilon's role in regular expressions?

Tags: automation, regular-language, computation-theory

I'm taking a class on the theory of computation and there's something I'm not quite grasping about ε in regular expressions. For example, my textbook says the following RE can be simplified as such (U denotes the Union operation and the alphabet is {0,1})

(0 U ε)1* = 01* U 1*

Shouldn't it just be 01* since ε is the empty string? Isn't it basically a concatenation of {0} and 1*?

Also, is ε considered a symbol in an alphabet? In other words, if a language allows ε as a string, is {ε, 0, 1} a suitable alphabet or is the ε simply omitted?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use 01* as this would not allow strings containing only 1's, but only strings containing a 0 followed by zero or more 1's. That is, the Regex (0 U ε)1* allows strings such as 0, 1, 01, 11, 011, 111, 0111, ... because you can choose to use the 0 or omit it, but 01* does not allow you to omit 0 and therefore contains the strings 0, 01, 011, 0111, ..., but not the strings 1, 11, 111, ...

You usually do not mention ε as being part of the alphabet.